# create unique profile page for each user python

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, jinja2, user-profile

I am using google app engine in python with a Jinja2 template engine.

This may be a silly solution but I have a list of a few thousand users and right now they can only access their own profile pages and have to be logged in to do it.  I would like to give every user a unique URL for their profile page and I am wondering how to do it.  I am not sure if this would work but could something like this be feasible?

```
class ProfilePage
    userlist = GQL query to return all users in the system
    user = users.get_by_id()
    for user in userlist:
        id = user.federated_id

        posts = GQL query to return all posts by that user

        self.render('/profile/id', posts=posts)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/profile/([0-9]+)', ProfilePage),])
```

My HTML for the profile page just displays the user's name and then displays all of their recent posts.

Update:

So here is my current code but I am just getting a 404 error:

```
class ProfilePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, profile_id):
    user = User.get_by_id(profile_id)
    #profile_id = some unique field
    if user:
       #Get all posts for that user and render....
       theid = user.theid
       personalposts = db.GqlQuery("select * from Post where theid =:1 order by created desc limit 30", theid)
    else:
        personalposts = None
    global visits
    logout = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
    currentuser = users.get_current_user()
    self.render('profile.html', user = currentuser, visits = visits, logout=logout, personalposts=personalposts)
```

How can I test it out I tried just entering www.url.com/profile/https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlILoSKGNwU5RuTiRtXug1l8raLEv5-mZg

Update:
The ID I was retrieving was not their OpenID URL but rather a app specific id that each user is given and thus that is the correct  to use

Comment: Look at the answer that I posted to the very similar question at
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256738/create-permenant-unique-links-based-on-a-user-id

Answer (score 2, accepted):

An easy way to do this would be to assign a unique URL identifier to each user (or use their key name), that way you can query the user by their ID or do a query based on a unique URL identifier property. You can also use their federated_id if you wanted.

Example:

```
class User(ndb.Model):
  unique_identifier = ndb.StringProperty()
  ...

class ProfilePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, profile_id):
    #profile_id = key name of user
    user = User.get_by_id(profile_id)
    #profile_id = some unique field
    #user = User.query(User.unique_identifier == profile_id).get()
    if user:
       #Get all posts for that user and render....


app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/profile/<profile_id>', ProfilePage),])
```

Comment: and with that code would the unique profile site stay the same when another user (possibly not logged in) visits it?

Comment: Yes, it uses the parameter in the URL as an identifier for whose profile page to load, not the currently logged in user

Comment: I just updated the code, as I said I'm getting a 404 error.  any ideas?

Comment: From your duplicate posted question I gather you are not using the proper regex expression, also, are your User model key names their OpenID login URLs? I expect not so you should look at the user entity's id/key name and try using that in your URL, not their OpenID URL. Please post your User model code and update your regex to the example I've given (you can use `<profile_id>` since it becomes a named parameter).

Comment: ah you are correct I was trying to use the OpenID URL but the actual ID value is just a random number and thanks for the hint that <profile_id> is an actual parameter.  thanks for the help!