# create permenant unique links based on a user ID

Tags: python, google-app-engine, jinja2, user-profile, webapp2

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [create unique profile page for each user python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11250728/create-unique-profile-page-for-each-user-python)

I am using google appengine with python and jinja2 and trying to give each user in my app a unique URL to their profile page that can be visited by anyone without logging in.  Here is my code thus far:

```
class ProfilePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def get(self, profile_id):
    user = User.get_by_id(profile_id)
    #profile_id = some unique field
    if user:
       #Get all posts for that user and render....
       theid = user.theid
       personalposts = db.GqlQuery("select * from Post where theid =:1 order by created desc limit 30", theid)
    else:
        personalposts = None
    global visits
    logout = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
    currentuser = users.get_current_user()
    self.render('profile.html', user = currentuser, visits = visits, logout=logout, personalposts=personalposts)

app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               ('/profile/([0-9]+)', ProfilePage),])
```

When I try and test it it just gives me a 404 error.  I suppose if the code is right I might be using the wrong testing URL.  For example if this is their OpenID ID:  How can I test it out I tried just entering www.url.com/profile/https://www.google.com/accounts/o8/id?id=AItOawlILoSKGNwU5RuTiRtXug1l8raLE45g-56 would just the id="this part" be what I put so I would have:

```
url = www.url.com/profile/AItOawlILoSKGNwU5RuTiRtXug1l8raLE45g-56
```

That's what I tried and it didn't quite work.  Thanks in advance for the help!

Answer (score 1):

The url that your are using (www.url.com/profile/**AItOawlILoSKGNwU5RuTiRtXug1l8raLE45g-56**) the last part of the url is a full key to the entity while in the code your are using the entity id to load it (using get_by_id() ).

Comment: it isn't a secret URL, I want it to be public. that's the whole reason for this, so that everyone can see it

Comment: where I am doing that? I'm not quite sure what that means...

Answer (score 1):

Try this regular expression:

```
r'^/profile/\w*?-(\d+)$'
```

Though I also must tell you that this is a very bad idea!

Comment: is that bad just because then anyone can put anything there?

Comment: You're using a parameterized query, so it's not an issue. Just don't use the value anywhere else (e.g. don't echo it into a page).