# 404 error on unique page creation with google app engine

Tags: python, google-app-engine, url-mapping

I asked a similar question here: [create permenant unique links based on a user ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11256738/create-permenant-unique-links-based-on-a-user-id) but couldn't quite get an answer.  I am trying to give every user on my site a unique profile page.  I have it mostly set up but I keep getting a 404 error.  Now I am not sure if it is a problem with my handler or just the whole way I am doing it.

Here is my app code:

```
app = webapp2.WSGIApplication([('/', MainPage),
                               (r'/profile/(.+)', ProfilePage)])
```

and here is my ProfilePage handler class:

```
class ProfilePage(webapp2.RequestHandler):
    def get(self, profile_id):
        profileowner = User.get_by_id(profile_id)

        if profileowner:
            #Get all posts for that user and render....
            #theid is their federated_id 
            theid = profileowner.theid
            personalposts = db.GqlQuery("select * from Post where theid =:1 order by created desc limit 30", theid)

            #I collect this so that I can have their username in the top of the page
            global visits
            logout = users.create_logout_url(self.request.uri)
            currentuser = users.get_current_user()
            self.render('profile.html', user = currentuser, visits = visits, logout=logout, personalposts=personalposts)
        else:
            self.redirect("/")
```

For an ID of 1201, which I found in the datastore viewer for a use, I have been testing it by typing in www.url.com/profile/1201 and that is when I get the 404 error.

Update:
It now is redirecting me to the main page with Amber's suggested change.

Now when I change this line:

```
profileowner = User.get_by_id(profile_id)
```

to this:

```
profileowner = User.get_by_id(17001)
```

it goes through correctly so I am guessing that that line is not correctly getting the profile_id from the URL

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
r'/profile/<profile_id>'
```

is not a valid regular expression. You probably want something like this instead:

```
r'/profile/(.+)'
```

Comment: then it just redirects me to ("/"

Comment: Okay, that means that you're supplying an invalid id. What URL are you trying to visit? Have you tried converting the id to an integer?

Comment: http://www.url.com/profile/17001 and the 17001 I am getting from my app engine dataviewer under the Name/ID column.  I just updated the question a bit with more info.

Comment: Try putting an `int()` around `profile_id` and see if that helps.